# integer promotion rules (bitshift and &)

Tags: c, c99

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t bitsLow;
uint16_t bitsHigh;
uint32_t statusBits;
...
bitsHigh = (statusBits >> 8) & 0xffff;
bitsLow = statusBits & 0xff;
```

Does it make any sense from perspective of integer promotion rules in 
following:

```
bitsHigh = (statusBits >> 8) & 0xffffU;
bitsLow = statusBits & 0xffU;
```

(as I understand 0xff or 0xffff has by default integer type)

Comment: What do you mean by "it makes sense"?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Note that in these cases, you don't need any masking at all.

Comment: Oli, I mean if putting a qualifier to a constant like 0xff would help getting integral promotion faster. You say I don't need masking because the resulting type will fir only 16 and 8 bits ?

Comment: @JensGustedt hexadecimal constants are always unsigned... except when they are signed.